# How to insert data into many database tables received from a single form?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have three tables in database: properties, features and feature_property_map.

Schema of properties table:

```
property_id
title
address
```

Schema of features table:

```
feature_id
feature_name
```

Schema of features_property_map table:

```
id
feature_id
property_id
```

I want data received from a form whose input fields are to be inserted into the above tables:

```
title
address
features (features are selected using checkboxes).
```

I am using PDO, so please give answer accordingly.

Comment: I would doubt that you're going to get an answer here. We won't do your work for you. Find some tutorials (https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+pdo+example), start writing your code, and when you get stuck post here and we'll help you out.

Comment: what's the problem? IF you need to run insert on more table just call PDO the number you want

Comment: What @yes123 said: if you know PDO well, do whatever it is you need to do to store the data in 1 table, several times (adjusting for the table and column names each time).

Comment: @Jesse Bunch, I do not want you to do my work.I know PDO well.I do not want you to write code.You can just provide me hint.It seems to me that you have not understood my problem.Let me give you an example,I have a real estate site.Where user can post their homes for sale.Every home have title,address which are stored in properties table.It also have features which are stored in features table and features_property_map table stores information that the home have which features.Now I want data received from a form as described in question to be inserted into the database.

Comment: @sunil - You didn't tell me anything more than what was in your original question. Do some reading on PDO connections in PHP, specifically `PDO::query`, `PDO::prepare`, and `PDO::execute`. There are all kinds of examples and commentary in the actual PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: @Jesse Bunch,Let me simply it.I have a form for which home owner fills to upload their home on our site.They fill title of home,address and features(features are select boxes).After receiving data we will run a query to insert title and address into 'properties' table.And features will be stored into features_property_map table,in this table we will store id of the features that home owner selected and id of property,these are stored using another query.but here i am having problem as I do not know id of the just inserted property.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you process the form data in PHP after submission, and then insert each piece of data into the correct fields, as required by your DB structure....

To get the ID after each INSERT, use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)